# Segmentation Fault when checking for NULL Node

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault

I am creating a Priority Queue with a merge, insert, and fetch functions. A test program inserts nodes by providing the data and priority, I create the node and attempt to place it within a Leftist Tree Heap Priority Queue.

This is the code for the class Node:

```cpp
template <class DATA>
class Node {
    public :
    DATA data ;
    double priority ;
    unsigned distance ;
    Node<DATA> * left , * right ;

    Node ( DATA & d , double prio ) : data (d) , priority(prio) ,
    distance(0) , left(NULL) , right(NULL) {} ;
} ;
```

This is my code to insert a node using a merge and swap:

```cpp
template<class DATA> 
Node<DATA> *
PQueue<DATA> :: merge ( Node<DATA> * p , Node<DATA> * q )
{
    unsigned d1, d2;

    if ( p == NULL ) return q ;
    if ( q == NULL ) return p ;

    if ( (p->priority) < (q->priority) ) // p is final root.
        swap(p,q) ;

    p->right = merge ( p->right , q );

    d1 = p->left->distance;
    d2 = p->right->distance;

    if ( d1 < d2 ) 
        swap(p->left,p->right) ; // leftist tree.

    p->distance = 1 + p->right->distance ;

    return p ;
}

template<class DATA>
void
PQueue<DATA> :: swap (Node<DATA> * p, Node<DATA> * q )
{
    Node<DATA> * temp;
    temp = p;
    p = q;
    q = temp;
    delete temp;
}

template < class DATA >
bool 
PQueue<DATA> :: insertPQ ( DATA & data , double priority )
{
    root = merge(root, new Node<DATA>(data, priority));
    return true;
}
```

The test code for the insert is this:

```cpp
pq.insertPQ( data[i] , data[i] )
```

The first insert works fine. The second insert gets to the merge function, enters the first recursive loop at `p->right = merge ( p->right , q );` and gives a seg fault on the if `( p == NULL ) return q ;` After doing some checking p does = NULL at this point yet I get the error when checking if `p == NULL`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's not really crashing where you think it is.

You have a couple bugs, though.
First, note that your swap function swaps the pointers it's given, but that has no effect whatsoever on the tree. I think you meant to make those arguments references: `swap (Node<DATA> *&p, Node<DATA> *&q)`

Second, note that you delete a node there, but you haven't allocated one. You're freeing the p node. This can cause a segfault.